# Sqlite database practice with android not working

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have made a very simple demo application of Sqlite databse in android .inthat an activity contains an EditText and a button and a textxView,
I have created handler class and also implemented java code for mainActivity,But its not working..I have made it from below link :
http://stdioe.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-connect-sqlite-database-in.html

But it shows error in myActivity.java file in line "private DB names;"....please help me...what it is?

my code is as below:

```
**main.xml**

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**DBcontroller.java**

```
package com.example.dbbb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBcontroller extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String MY_DATABASE ="name";
public static final int VERSION =1;
    public DBcontroller(Context context) {
        super(context, MY_DATABASE, null, VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mynames(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT);");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mynames");
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

**main.java**

```
package com.example.dbbb;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
EditText et;
Button b;
private DB names;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        names = new DB(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 try{
                     AddDATA(name.getText().toString());
                     Cursor cursor = ShowDATA();
                     ShowDATA(cursor);
                     }
                     finally{
                     names.close();
                    }
            }
        });

    }

     private void AddDATA(String ResultName){

            SQLiteDatabase db = names.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues datas = new ContentValues();
            datas.put("name", ResultName);
            db.insertOrThrow("ournames", null, datas);
            }

            private String[] SELECT = {"id", "name"};

            private Cursor ShowDATA(){
            SQLiteDatabase db = names.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("ournames", SELECT, null, null, null, null, null);

            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            return cursor;
            }

            private void ShowDATA(Cursor cursor){
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("RESULTS!:\n");

                while(cursor.moveToNext()){

                String whatthenameis = cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
                builder.append(whatthenameis).append("\n");
                }

                TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                text.setText(builder);
            }

}
```

Comment: What is DB supposed to be? What type of object?

Comment: brother i lso confused as i have downloaded this code from the given URL...DId you gone thru it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it shows error in myActivity.java file in line "private DB names;"....please help me...what it is?

You are referring to this line:

```
private DB names;
```

You have not imported the class `DB` in `MainActivity`, and are trying to use it. Eclipse cannot resolve the class for the object, so it shows an error on that line.

You can try `Source -> Organize Imports` to import the right classes.

### Edit

Looking at the blog, it looks like they are referring to their implementation of `SQLiteOpenHelper` when they use `DB`, apparently whoever wrote this never tried to compile it. Change `DB` to `DBcontroller` for your code:

Here:

```
private DBcontroller names;
```

And here:

```
names = new DBcontroller(this);
```

Comment: Sir...i Exactly dont know what is "DB"..thats y i have post this question,,,please refer Link..may be you can help me by it..thanks

Comment: probably `DB` stands for the `Database` class from the first part of the tutorial. Replace `DB` with `Database`.

Comment: @mihail yes in the blog they use `Database`, but @jigar is using `DBcontroller`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you showed us, you don't have a class called DB. There is no existing class called DB provided by android as far as I know, thus making it non existent(unless you are hiding it from us).

This basically just means that you should replace DB with DBController and it should not show that error anymore. Providing you also have the right import.

**EDIT**

For a solution in code, see Steven Byle's answer.

I just wanted to provide my 2 cents on why DB gives an error.

Comment: Excellent job copying my answer ;)

Comment: @StevenByle You are right that it's pretty much a copy. Same code, different explanation. That was the point of my answer. I didn't find your answer explaining WHY DB doesn't work well enough. So I wrote it myself. I should have written a comment perhaps. Sorry for that.

Comment: @StevenByle Editted my answer, to avoid violating copy rights on your answer

Comment: Hehe I was just giving you a hard time, no worries

Answer (score 0):

**db** shouldn't be string type. **db** should be datbase object where you have extends **SqliteOpenHelper**

```
Database db=new Database(getApplicationContext());
```

or

```
Database db=new Database(class.this);
```